# how to delete .svn directory in not a working copy

Tags: svn

I copyd a directory from a working copy, but found .svn directory in my copyd directory. I want to delete the .svn directory, I tried rm -fr .svn, but say Operation not permitted.
So, how to delete those .svn directory? thank you

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it says not permitted it means that there is a problem with access rights. If you can, run as root.

Also, SVN keeps a `.svn` directory in each project directory. so, you'll have to do something like

```
sudo find -type d -name "*.svn" | xargs sudo rm -rf
```

Note: both uses of `sudo` above are needed only when there are problems with access rights

Why is this related to access rights? See here.

```
mihai@fomalhault:/tmp$ sudo mkdir test
[sudo] password for mihai: 
mihai@fomalhault:/tmp$ rm -rf test/
rm: cannot remove directory `test': Operation not permitted
```

Running a strace gives a

```
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "test", AT_REMOVEDIR) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

and this is what's reported

Comment: If he had the right to create it, he has the right to delete it as well.

Comment: Yes, but maybe he copied them while being `root`. I saw this happening more than once

Comment: "Operation not permitted", "Operation not permitted"... that's EPERM, **not** EACCESS. Egro, it's not an access rights issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can simpler create this by using the svn export command which export the whole working copy without the .svn folders. You can also export parts of your working copy.